# What is the difference between ArrayList and ObservableList?

Tags: java, javafx-2

Currently I am working with database on javafx and have no idea about ObservableList, can I use ArrayList instead of ObservableList?

Comment: The difference is that one list is observable, the other is not.

Comment: @Filburt Look at fabian's answer. It seems to be based on experience more than knowledge. This seems to be a fair question to me.

Comment: The ObservableList will let JavaFX know that it has been changed so that the user interface can be updated. ArrayList won't do that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That depends. If you need a `ObservableList`, you cannot use `ArrayList` directly. `ObservableList` adds a way to listen for changes on a list which `ArrayList` does not implement.

However you could use a `ArrayList` as backing list of a `ObservableList`

```
ArrayList<T> list = ...
ObservableList<T> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
```

Note that in this case you should make sure you're not modifying the list through any means but `observableList`, since otherwise the listeners won't be triggered.

Note that `FXCollections` also provides a method for creating a `ObservableList` backed by a `ArrayList` without having to deal with the `ArrayList` itself:

```
ObservableList<T> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Answer (score 3):

**ArrayList:** Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null.

**ObservableList:** A list that allows listeners to track changes when they occur.

Answer (score 2):

It depends of your case. If you want to show this list in for example tableView or other view then you should use Observable collection which contains listeners ect and other components necessery for doing interaction with view.